# How to delete random number sequence

Tags: c

I am new to C programming.

I am trying to work through an example in my textbook.

Problem:

1 : Can't make random number generator pause for one second, without having to 
insert printf(); in a place where I shouldn't.

2: Can't make the program pause for 1 second, and then delete random sequence. I have tried using printf(\r), but it just deletes the entire sequence without pausing for 1 second.

Help appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{        
    time_t Start_Of_Seq = (time(NULL));

    time_t Now = 0;     
    Now = clock();

    srand((unsigned int)Start_Of_Seq);

    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    { 
        printf("%d",rand()% 10);
    }

    printf("\n"); //This shouldn't be here.

    for(; clock() - Now < CLOCKS_PER_SEC;);

    printf("Testing the to see if there is a pause\n");
}
```

Comment: You currently have more than one problem in that question. If you can reproduce any of them alone (which I naively assume) please work out an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for each of them and post separate questions.

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve, i.e. what useful task is the program supposed to perform? It seems to me that you might have gotten lost in workarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `printf` function outputs everything to a buffer. The buffer is actually printed only after a newline. Try `fflush(stdout);` to print the buffer contents immediately.

Besides, if you use Linux or another Unix-like system, for pauses there is a system call `sleep`.  Try the `man 3 sleep` command to see more info.